# Batch files for saving several pdf as reduced size pdf

Tags: pdf, batch-file

I have several PDF in my server machine. they are taking lot of space. We are trying to reduce the size of PDF to optimize PDF scrolling performance and reduce size consumption. We have thought of using Adobe Acrobat 11 SDK. While using the trial, I have found the way of reducing PDF size by
file>saveasother>reducedsize PDF

Is any batch file possible that can reduce the size of PDF on the given folders. Alternatively a JavaScript or IAC would be also possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Acrobat Pro *has* a "batch" command: menu "Advanced > Document processing > Batch processing" (on Acrobat Pro X). One of the provided samples is "Save optimized"; by default it runs on 'selected files' -- unfortunately, you can't select a folder.

Comment: if you provide the Acrobat commands, I make the batch.

Comment: Is the above process file>saveasother>reducedsize PDF good or you need something else.

Comment: is any more information required from me to create batch?